# How can I draw a table to dendrogram?

Tags: r

Im very newly start to study R and python...

I want to draw a table to dendrogram-like graph

Just want to show the relations from top to bottom

Relations could be overlapped.

Here is the thing I want to draw

[image: dendrogram-like plot from excel table]

I will be very appreciate for your help.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this in R. You may wish to look at the `igraph` and `DiagrammeR` packages in particular.

However, if you wanted to plot it from scratch, you could do something like:

```r
df$top_x    <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$Top))/(length(unique(df$Top)) + 1)
df$mid1_x   <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$Mid1))/(length(unique(df$Mid1)) + 1)
df$mid2_x   <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$Mid2))/(length(unique(df$Mid2)) + 1)
df$bottom_x <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$Bottom))/(length(unique(df$Bottom)) + 1)
df$top_y    <- 0.8
df$mid1_y   <- 0.6
df$mid2_y   <- 0.4
df$bottom_y <- 0.2

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(top_x, top_y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = mid1_x, yend = mid1_y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = mid1_x, y = mid1_y, xend = mid2_x, yend = mid2_y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = mid2_x, y = mid2_y, xend = bottom_x, yend = bottom_y)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = Top), size = 8) +
  geom_label(aes(label = Mid1, x = mid1_x, y = mid1_y), size = 8) +
  geom_label(aes(label = Mid2, x = mid2_x, y = mid2_y), size = 8) +
  geom_label(aes(label = Bottom, x = bottom_x, y = bottom_y), size = 8) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

**Data used**

```r
df <- data.frame(Top = "A", Mid1 = rep(1:3, each = 2), 
                 Mid2 = rep(c("T", "U"), each = 3), 
                 Bottom = c("F", "S", "S", "H", "H", "K"))
df
#>   Top Mid1 Mid2 Bottom
#> 1   A    1    T      F
#> 2   A    1    T      S
#> 3   A    2    T      S
#> 4   A    2    U      H
#> 5   A    3    U      H
#> 6   A    3    U      K
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful to solving my task. Sorry for the late comment. Thx a lot.